# I disabled SMB1 on my file server, now the mounted shares on the client stopped working. How can I mount non SMB1 file shares on my ubuntu client?

Tags: networking, samba, fstab, cifs, smb

I recently disabled SMB1 (adding `min protocol = SMB2` to smb.conf) on my file server (samba 4.3.9) because of reasons.

Windows clients can still access the file shares, but I also have some mounted network folders on ubuntu clients and they currently fail. The client is currently mounting the shares on folders in fstab using cifs.

What should I do to fix this? What is best practice for permanently mounting network shares on Ubuntu Server 16.04.1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just discovered this link as I deactivated SMB1 on a Win 2008 R2 server and my Ubuntu Server had issues connecting with CIFS.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120677/can-not-use-mount-cifs-mount-error2-no-such-file-or-directory

> vers=
>              SMB protocol version. Allowed values are:
>
> ```
>        ·   1.0 - The classic CIFS/SMBv1 protocol. This is the default.
>
>        ·   2.0 - The SMBv2.002 protocol. This was initially introduced in Windows Vista Service Pack 1, and
>            Windows Server 2008. Note that the initial release version of Windows Vista spoke a slightly
>            different dialect (2.000) that is not supported.
>
>        ·   2.1 - The SMBv2.1 protocol that was introduced in Microsoft Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008R2.
>
>        ·   3.0 - The SMBv3.0 protocol that was introduced in Microsoft Windows 8 and Windows Server 2012.
> ```

I added `,vers=2.1` as an option to the `/etc/fstab` line to resolve it as apparently cifs defaults to SMB1.